# Subscribe to mail folders with evolution-ews on an EWS server

Tags: server, email, evolution, ms-exchange

I am using the `evolution` email client with the `evolution-ews` ([github](https://github.com/GNOME/evolution-ews)) *Exchange Web Services* (EWS) *integration* package to connect to our companys Microsoft EWS server.

I have some server side rules sorting email to folders.

Is there any way to configure the client to "**check for new messages in subscribed folders**"? This is a "Receiving option" that is by default available for IMAP servers.

Answer (score 2):

Via Edit - Preferences - Mail Accounts - Edit
[image]

Comment: Not exactly what I asked, since this will check for **all** folders. A reasonable fallback however, if _subscribed folders_ is not available.